# Recurring Events in Calendar created from a template

Tags: list-view, lookup-column, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

Using SharePoint 2013 on-premise, I had a `calendar` working nicely in my test environment. I then Saved it to a template, moved it to another site collection and created a new calendar. It had `lookup columns` to other `lists` which I also migrated and needed to recreate the lookup columns to get it all working again. The calendar is now working well except for the following issues, which did not exist in the source calendar in my test environment.

1. When I create a recurring event, and then try to delete just one
   instance/occurrence (item) of the series I get an error, with a correlation ID that is not showing up in logs. Deleting individual (non recurring events) is working fine. Deleting an entire series is also working fine.
2. I have one column (it's a lookup column) that works in the `NewForm.aspx`, displays the correct selected item in the default `DispForm.aspx`, but does not show selected in the default `EditForm.aspx`. I created a new (unedited) default Edit Form and the problem persists. I have a second lookup column that pulls different information from the same list at it works fine.

I do not know if these issues are all related, and thought it might be helpful to put them all in one question so you have a full picture.